# Generating Tensor RT Engine for YOLOP on Jetson Nano

Tags: linux, tensorflow, pytorch, tensorrt, nvidia-jetson-nano

Before I state the issue I want to introduce the YOLOP model from pytorch see on [Github](https://stackoverflow.com)

The authors used Tensorrt to inference the model on Nvidia Jetson TX2. In the source code,they have provided a code for deployment and reasoning of model in ./toolkits/deploy.
In my project, I wanted to deploy it in jetson nano. I have successfully generated the build files based from the instruction from github:

```
cd toolkits/deploy
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
```

Output:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found CUDA: /usr/local/cuda-10.2 (found version "10.2") 
-- Found OpenCV: /usr (found version "4.1.1") 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/nvidia/Desktop/YOLOP/toolkits/deploy/build
```

But when after the `make` command it outputs the errors it so long but I can provide the beginning and end of the error:
nvidia@ubuntu:~/Desktop/YOLOP/toolkits/deploy/build$ make
[ 25%] Building NVCC (Device) object CMakeFiles/myplugins.dir/myplugins_generated_yololayer.cu.o
/home/nvidia/Desktop/YOLOP/toolkits/deploy/yololayer.h(60): error: member function declared with "override" does not override a base class member

/home/nvidia/Desktop/YOLOP/toolkits/deploy/yololayer.h(60): warning: function "nvinfer1::IPluginV2::enqueue(int32_t, const void *const *, void *const *, void *, cudaStream_t)" is hidden by "nvinfer1::YoloLayerPlugin::enqueue" -- virtual function override intended?

/home/nvidia/Desktop/YOLOP/toolkits/deploy/yololayer.h(91): warning: function "nvinfer1::IPluginV2Ext::configurePlugin(const nvinfer1::Dims *, int32_t, const nvinfer1::Dims *, int32_t, const nvinfer1::DataType *, const nvinfer1::DataType *, const __nv_bool *, const __nv_bool *, nvinfer1::PluginFormat, int32_t)" is hidden by "nvinfer1::YoloLayerPlugin::configurePlugin" -- virtual function override intended?

/home/nvidia/Desktop/YOLOP/toolkits/deploy/yololayer.h(93): error: exception specification for virtual function "nvinfer1::YoloLayerPlugin::detachFromContext" is incompatible with that of overridden function "nvinfer1::IPluginV2Ext::detachFromContext"

/home/nvidia/Desktop/YOLOP/toolkits/deploy/yololayer.h(91): error: exception specification for virtual function "nvinfer1::YoloLayerPlugin::configurePlugin" is incompatible with that of overridden function "nvinfer1::IPluginV2IOExt::configurePlugin(const nvinfer1::PluginTensorDesc *, int32_t, const nvinfer1::PluginTensorDesc *, int32_t)"

```
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/myplugins.dir/myplugins_generated_yololayer.cu.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/myplugins.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/myplugins.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Solution(s) I tried:
-checked if packages needed are installed like ZED, Cuda, and libnvinfer.
-tried to modify the yololayer.h and .cu

Still it gives the error. Any comments, advice, and suggestions are great help.